# Вывод двумерного массива на C

Tags: c, массивы

Пытаюсь вывести в цикле for с помощью printf двумерный массив по индексу. На C++ это сделать легко, но мне нужно именно на си. При некоторых попытках вывести массив возникает исключение "нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу", которое вызывает printf.

Одна из немногих ситуаций, где без проблем портировать из под C++ на C не получается :(

Comment: Покажите код вашего двумерного массива, желаемый вывод и желательно код вашей попытки

Comment: Покажите ваш код. Странно, что вы можете сделать на С++, но не на С...

Comment: Покажите как вы пытаетесь выводить массив и мы скажем почему возникает исключение.

Comment: Например, так `void
print_int_matrix (int *arr_begin, int rows, int cols)
{   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)   printf("%d ", arr_begin[i * cols + j]); puts("");  } }`  для `int a[5][8];` вызываем `print_int_matrix((int *)a, 5, 8);`  / Т.е. рассматриваем память двумерного массива как одномерный и сами (вместо компилятра) вычисляем адреса элементов матрицы

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример вывода двумерного массива заполненого случайными числами в заданном диапазоне

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>


int main()
{
    int q;
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    printf("Введите количество строк и столбцов в матрице: ");
    scanf("%d", &q);
    int a[q][q];
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    printf("Матрица:\n");
    for(int m = 0; m < q; m++)
    {
     for(int f = 0; f < q; f++)
    {
        a[m][f] =-99 + rand()%199;
        printf("%4d ",a[m][f]);     //если надо чтобы элементы массива были пронумированы  printf("(%d.%d)%4d ",m,f,a[m][f]);
    } 
    printf("\n");   
    }   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я уже сам понял, что printf не может прямиком указывать на map[i][j], это нужно делать через параметры.